# Can I get global mouse event on Unity using MSLLHOOKSTRUCT

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine

First and foremost, I am a complete beginner, I apologies in advance if I'm not clear enough and I truly thank you for taking the time to read this!

I'm working on unity on a way to create a global mouse event tracker in order to record the inputs from the mouse event when the window isn't in focus. There is a library called **[UnityRawInput](https://github.com/Elringus/UnityRawInput)** that allows you to get global inputs in unity just like what I want, but for the keyboard.

The program in c# first sets the hook (*which I think I nailed for the mouse, but not to sure about that*) and then calls a function **HandleLowLevelHookProc** which allow to get the *wParam* and *lParam* from the function **CallNextHookEx** to get keys and their states like that :

```cs
var kbd = KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT.CreateFromPtr(lParam);
var keyState = (RawKeyState)wParam;
var key = (RawKey)kbd.vkCode;
```

For each key switch, the functions HandleKeyDown and HandleKeyUp are informed of the switch and by adding listeners, you can know what key is being pressed or released (*or at least that's how I think that works*), HandleKeyDown is for example as follows :

```cs
private static void HandleKeyDown (RawKey key)
{
    var added = pressedKeys.Add(key);
    if (added && OnKeyDown != null) OnKeyDown.Invoke(key);
}
```

So my question is the following, can I modify that script to get the same behavior with the mouse, which is for example having the debug log recognize the clicks outside of the player.
I've tried naively to modify the code as such, which didn't work of course :

```cs
var ms = MSLLHOOKSTRUCT.CreateFromPtr(lParam);
var keyState = (RawKeyState)wParam;
var key = (RawKey)ms.mouseData;
```

I've changed the RawKeyState so that the identifier of the mouse message is coherent with the values provided here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v=vs.85)

I think that my problem resides in my lack of understanding of the global mouse structure : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msllhookstruct

I honestly have no idea how much information I need to provide, if you have any hint or recommendation or if I'm completely lost, feel free to tell me :D

Answer (score 0):

The hook can be installed using a windows hook like you mentioned, however you also need to implement a message loop on a separate thread to manage the hook(s).

The following unity script will get you there :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseHookScript : MonoBehaviour
{
static bool created = false;

static public System.IntPtr OnMouseHook(int nCode, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (MouseMessage.WM_LBUTTONUP == (MouseMessage)wParam)
    {
        Debug.Log("Left Button Clicked");
    }
    // Here, you can handle global mouse messages.
    return CallNextHookEx(new System.IntPtr(0), nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
enum MouseMessage
{
    WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
}

private static HookProc _mouseHook;
private static System.IntPtr _hMouseHook;

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern System.IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern System.IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(System.IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(System.IntPtr hhk);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern System.IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(HookType hookType, HookProc lpfn, System.IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern System.IntPtr CallNextHookEx(System.IntPtr hhk, int nCode, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetMessage(out MSG lpMsg, System.IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsgFilterMin, uint wMsgFilterMax);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool TranslateMessage([System.Runtime.InteropServices.In] ref MSG lpMsg);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern System.IntPtr DispatchMessage([System.Runtime.InteropServices.In] ref MSG lpmsg);

public delegate System.IntPtr HookProc(int nCode, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam);

public enum HookType : int
{
    WH_MOUSE_LL = 14
}
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
    public System.Int32 x;
    public System.Int32 Y;
}
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MSG
{
    public System.IntPtr hwnd;
    public uint message;
    public System.IntPtr wParam;
    public System.IntPtr lParam;
    public uint time;
    public POINT pt;
}
public static void DoWork()
{


    var hModule = GetModuleHandle(null);

    _mouseHook = OnMouseHook;
    _hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(
        HookType.WH_MOUSE_LL,
        _mouseHook,
        hModule,
        0);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(out msg, System.IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(ref msg);
        DispatchMessage(ref msg);
    }


}



void Start()
{
    if (!created)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread thread1 = new System.Threading.Thread(DoWork);
        thread1.Start();
        created = true;
    }
}
void Exit()
{
    if (created)
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hMouseHook);
        created = false;
        }
    }
}
```